# JS bottlenecks in Chrome Timeline

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have been doing some performance checking on my website and using timeline i get a warning about possible bottlenecks, but does not really explain how to solve it.

This is what i see in my time line:

[image]

`Large image link:` https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdzvI.jpg

If you see the `setCenter` function that has this code:

```
function setCenter(div){    
    var testH = document.getElementById(div).offsetHeight;
    var testW = document.getElementById(div).offsetWidth;
    var height = settings.height;
    var width = settings.width;

    var temp = Math.floor( (height / 2)- ( test / 2 )) + 'px'; 
    document.getElementById(div).style.marginTop = temp;    

    var temp = Math.floor( (width / 2)- (  testW /2 )) + 'px'; 
    document.getElementById(div).style.marginLeft = temp;
}
```

What exactly is wrong with the function to give me such a warning about a bottleneck ? I cannot see any other solution that would be any better.

Can some one explain what I need to do to solve this?

Comment: You don’t need to solve it unless *you* think your website’s performance is becoming a problem. Is `setCenter` called on a lot of elements and during actual, common actions? The timeline said it took 4 milliseconds, so it doesn’t really seem like a problem at the moment, hence a warning and not an error. You might consider finding a better way of centering using CSS if possible, though.

Comment: Well i don't think there is a CSS solution because JS populates the div, so i would need to get the div's dimensions first before centering it...but what does it mean by invalidated layout?

Comment: `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` makes the browser recompute the layout to ensure that you get correct values. Whether it is really an issue I cannot say.

Comment: Is there a better solution for getting offsetHeight etc?

Comment: @FelixKling would getting the divs style width and margins/paddings and calculating it manually be less likely to cause the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading and writing from the DOM is inherently slow in browsers. Nicholas Zakas in his book [High Performance Javascript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059680279X) discusses this in great detail in Chapter 3. One way to speed up DOM interactions which he notes is to do all of your reads together and then all of your writes together. Taking that into consideration, your function might instead look like this:

```
function setCenter(div){
    var div = document.getElementById(div);    // only read this once and store it
    var testH = div.offsetHeight;
    var testW = div.offsetWidth;
    var height = settings.height;
    var width = settings.width;

    // Do some logic
    var marginTop = Math.floor( (height / 2)- ( testH / 2 )) + 'px';
    var marginLeft = Math.floor( (width / 2)- (  testW /2 )) + 'px';  

    // Batch DOM update
    div.style.marginTop = marginTop;
    div.style.marginLeft = marginLeft;
}
```

Now you are only reading from the DOM once (instead of 4 times) and writing twice, but your writes are also grouped together which the browser may be able to batch together in the reflow process instead of being separated by computational logic.

Comment: Ah i see, although its the offsetHeight its not happy with, should i calculate its true offset by getting its paddings/margins and doing the calculations?

Comment: Possibly, I would experiment and try it. What I can tell you is that each time you check one of those values (offsetHeight, offsetWidth, clientHeight, clientWidth, scrollHeight, scrollWidth) it forces a browser reflow.

Comment: Yeh i think a JSPerf is in order! :) Thanks for the info!